# Append css to facebook iframe by jQuery?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

is there any way, to append css to a fb like Iframe?

I tried it this way:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
      var html = jQuery(".like_single iframe").contents().find("connect_widget_vertical_center").html();
      alert(html);
    });
```

And got this error in firebug:

Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'

Answer (score 2):

No. Since the contents of the iframe are served from a different domain, you don't have permission to access or modify the contents. This is a security feature enforced by the browser, called the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this:

```
$(function(){
  var html = $("connect_widget_vertical_center").html();
  alert(html);
});
```

Add this to the source of the iFrame, in the head section.